# List all classes tagged with a specific (custom) tag in a sandcastle documentation

Tags: .net, sandcastle, shfb, maml

Is there a way to create a list of all classes tagged with a specific (custom) tag in a Sandcastle documentation?

I'm using a custom tag to mark specific behavior in my classes. I mapped this tag in main_conceptual.xsl and the content is shown at the documentation sheet of each class.

Now I want create a special page (as conceptual content?) in the documentation which shows a list of all classes which are tagged with my custom tag. Is there a possibility to do this using sandcastle help file builder(SHFB)? Perhaps in the .xsl transformations? Or using MAML?